# How to convert git case to github

Tags: git, github

I'm working with react. I have separated the file name.tsx and several folders from uppercase to lowercase.
In github, the code is in uppercase, so I tried to change it using `rm` to change these to lowercase.

There are more than 50 folders and files that need to be changed, and it takes too long to change them one by one.

It is difficult to fix each one,
Isn't there a command that allows the modified files and folders to be modified by typing the command?

Comment: Are all the files and folders already renamed and you don‘t know, how to push to GitHub? Or you search for a Git-command to rename all the files?

Comment: I want the second.

Comment: Then just write a script, where you renaming all files and folders with following git command: `git mv old_filename new_filename`.